# Kernel 5.11 probably doesn't like my TPM settings (Asus X541UAK)

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, manjaro, kubuntu, pop-os

This week [I've tried](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1361844) several different Live USB Linux distros on my Asus X541UAK (4 GB RAM, 500 GB HDD, Inter Core i3-7100, Windows 10 Pro 19043 [latest], BIOS v311 [latest]):

1. **Manjaro 21.1.1**, with kernel **5.4**ª, started up instantly and ran flawlessly. Just perfection.

   a. **Kubuntu 20.04**, also with kernel 5.4 (which I tried a year ago, when it just came out), ran flawlessly, with no excess elements before startup.
2. **Kubuntu** and **Ubuntu Studio 20.04.2.0**, both with kernel **5.8**, showed an error

```
tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover t
he entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80
```

twice (two identical rows) before the respective logo appeared and the system checked all the files in itself, but after that it also ran flawlessly.

3. **Kubuntu** and **Ubuntu Studio 20.04.3**, both with kernel **5.11**, showed the same error screen, checked all their files, and that's all. Kubuntu has a "Try/Install" window before loading into Live session, and pressing Try button caused endless* loading; the rest of buttons were unclickable. Ubuntu Studio (with XFCE) didn't have a welcome window and loaded the desktop instantly. But none of apps (tried Firefox, Ardour, Okular) worked — they crashed with the `Crash reporter. The application has a problem and crashed` pop up appearing.

   a. **Pop!_OS 20.04** also seems to have kernel 5.11 (the devs don't mark which subversion of Ubuntu it's based on, most probably 20.04.3, since it's downloaded within this week) and behaves identically to Ubuntu Studio.

**I didn't wait for more than 5 minutes and turned off the laptop manually*

None of the images is corrupt, nor the USB sticks. The way of making em bootable (burning with Etcher, Rufus, creating a Ventoy partition) doesn't change anything.

The firmware bugs clearly show that there's something with my TPM, but my BIOS (even on latest version) doesn't have TPM even mentioned (although Windows shows that i have TPM 2.0 enabled).

Questions:

1. Is it actually about kernels? The most flawless of them, Manjaro, is an Arch derivative, the rest are Ubuntu derivatives.
2. If i'm about to use 5.11 kernel in future (I hope 5.13 or 5.14 won't have such an error), what can be the way to fix it?

ª**Update:** Manjaro (Aug 27th 2021) turned out to have kernel v5.13. I suggest that the error was fixed somewhere in .12 or .13. Sorry for misinformation

Comment: Try adding `module_blacklist=tpm-crb` as a kernel boot argument.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov how and where exactly? By pressing E in GRUB? I'm kinda noob in this stuff

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_boot_options_Permanently_for_an_Existing_Installation

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I see it works with Live USB too, right?

Comment: Yes ............

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I did it, and it behaves like 5.8 now: the error screen is the same, but the system loads and works great. Would you also know how to get rid of the errors completely?

Comment: File a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: I also have ASUS lapop (different model) that I've been using for five years or so with Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Linux Mint, KDE neon and finally SparkyLinux KDE. I've been getting this message in the past year or so only (with debian and ubuntu) although everything works perfectly. It seems it's just a minor warning that people compiling the linux kernel overlooked to suppress from the graphical interface of the boot process. Still searching for a solution get rid of this unseemly interruption of the graphical booting process. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `module_blacklist=tpm-crb` as a [kernel boot argument](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_boot_options_Permanently_for_an_Existing_Installation) might help.

If it does consider filing a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu).

Comment: In my experience, nothing done to blacklist the *tpm_crb* module gets rid of that message, probably because the command `sudo lsmod | grep tpm` poduces nothing, although I do have `/dev/tmp0` and some technical details from the command `sudo dmesg | grep -i tpm`.

Answer (score 0):

The message `tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80` displayed during graphical boot process simply notes that there's a firmware bug that **might** affect functioning of the Trusted Platform Module (TPM).

**This can safely be ignored** if the system works without any problem, although users might prefer having this not displayed at all during graphical boot process similar to other messages.

Some time ago, it was possible to **disable** (blacklist) the kernel modules **tpm** and **tpm_crb** when they were not deemed necessary or usable, or just to prevent such a useless message during graphical boot process, because they were **loadable modules** then; but **it has become impossible to disable (blacklist) them after TPM has been compiled inside the kernel recently in order to enable IMA, which relies on TPM**.

Therefore, **users can do nothing** about it unless the motherboard manufacturer has included an option to manually disable the Trusted Platform Module (TPM) in their BIOS utility. However, **linux kernel developers might be able to suppress this message**, and let the users see that warning message using **dmesg** as in many other similar cases.